# Have Gnosis Safe Pay Transaction Gas Fee

Tags: transactions, gas, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I am currently using gnosis safe. When the execution of any transaction is made, the signer has to pay the gas fee. I want all gas fees to be paid by the safe, not the signers, how can I make this possible?

Is there a workaround for this? I am currently interacting with the site app.safe.global.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page.

Hope it helps! Louis